# Simplest way to group by year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table **Employees** with the following attributes: **EmployeeID, DateOfHire, Name, Surname**.

The format of the **DateOfHire** is *YYY-MM-DD HH:HH:HH* (smalldatetime).
I am using Microsoft's SSMS.

I want to find how many employees were hired in each year.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DateOfHire), COUNT(EmployeeID) AS 
HiredEmployees
FROM Employees
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,DateOfHire)
```

this one works, but I'd prefer not to use **DATEPART**.

and this:

```
SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) AS HiredEmployees
FROM Employees
WHERE DateOfHire BETWEEN  '____-01-01 00:00:00' AND '____-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DateOfHire
```

The first one is ok, while the second one gives me a conversion error (smalldatetime - character string).

What's the easiest way to group employees by year of hire? Can it be done without using *DATEPART* or any function?

Comment: why not use of `year(getdate())` function ?

Comment: Is there a typo?  DateOfHireBETWEEN

Comment: @Danieboy Yes, sorry. I corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateOfHire), COUNT(EmployeeID) AS HiredEmployees
FROM Employees
GROUP BY YEAR(DateOfHire)
```

it will get you the year of each date in the Employees table and a count of employee ID's that match them.

This is assuming that the DateOfHire Field is a date column

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how your first one doesn't work:

```
select YEAR(DateOfHire) yr,COUNT(*) ct
from Employees
group by YEAR(DateOFHire)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `DATEPART` or a similar function is your best bet. The way you have your first section is just fine. I would suggest just using that. As an alternative, to make your code easier to read, you can use an inner select with `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(EmployeeID) FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        DATEPART(YEAR,DateOfHire) AS YearOfHire
    FROM Employees
)
GROUP BY YearOfHire
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to do it without subqueries and with a simpler function.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the easiest way to group employees by year of hire? Can it be done without using DATEPART or any function?

No. DATEPART or YEAR is your best options here. If you wish, you can create a computed column Year, which will be calculated from you datetime. Then you can group by this column without any function. And I would also sugest to create an index on this column for your query.

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
    ADD DateOfHireYear AS DATEPART(YEAR,DateOfHire) PERSISTED
GO

SELECT DateOfHireYear, COUNT(EmployeeID) AS 
HiredEmployees
FROM Employees
GROUP BY DateOfHireYear
```

Comment: This is not really the solution I was looking for. I was looking for something easier as I'm a beginner, but I appreciate it.